# friend array not returning the values in android

Tags: java, android

Hi in the below code friendinfo[] it getting all the friends in the array format.the output is like this [0],[1] but it's returning object not returning values.
After that when I am clicking the create button passing the parameter groupname,username,friends of the username.

Then I am clciking the function createGroup from imservice but friend values giving objects.

**java**

```
 create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String groupname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nick");


                        try {
                            FriendInfo[] friend=FriendController.getFriendsInfo();

                            String result1 = imService.CreateGroup(groupname,imService.getUsername(),friend);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Created Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**IMService.java**

```
public String CreateGroup(String groupname,String username,
            FriendInfo[] friend) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {




                String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(groupname,"UTF-8") +
                        "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&friendUserName=" +friend +        
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);      


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(groupname,"UTF-8") +
                    "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                    "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                    "&friendUserName=" +friend +        
                    "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                    "&";
```

Here you are appending your `friend` array to a `String`, which means `Object`'s default implementation of `toString` is applied on this array. If you want the elements of the array to be appended to the `String`, use `Arrays.toString(friend)` and override `toString()` in `FriendInfo` class in order to convert the information contained in `FriendInfo` to whatever format you desire :

```
            String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(groupname,"UTF-8") +
                    "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                    "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                    "&friendUserName=" +Arrays.toString(friend) +        
                    "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                    "&";
```

And in FriendInfo :

```
@Override
public String toString ()
{
    return ... // here you should append the properties of FriendInfo
               // in some easy to read format
}
```

Comment: @user1 java.util.Arrays is a class that contains static utility methods for arrays.

Comment: can you give me some example how to do that

Comment: @user1 added a partial example to the answer. I can't give more than that without knowing what FriendInfo class looks like.

Comment: then also it returning same like this FriendInfo@b2d66ab0

Comment: @user1 That means you didn't override toString in FriendInfo as I suggested.